# Meaning of plus in org mode documents

Tags: org-mode, outline

Sometimes I see folks using "+" to structure their org document.
What is the appropriate use case for plus.

[image]

Comment: (info "(org) Plain lists")

Answer (score 1):

The user is free to use plus as bullet for plain lists.  There is no special use case which is reserved for plus.

Follow the hint of Tyler [Jan 16 at 18:36] to find variants of plain lists within Org mode.